# How to understand that maven is built with maven?

Tags: maven

Being curious about how maven works exactly, I've checked out its source codes. Astonishingly, the maven modules are built themselves by maven. Can someone help me to understand how could this be possible?

Precisely, how is the maven binary, which is used to build maven sources, compiled?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)

Comment: thanks a lot for this link, very informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by the comment, the original version was probably compiled by a different compiler, but subsequent versions have since been bootstrapped.

Edit: as noted I meant built, not compiled.  My mistake

Comment: I bet it was the same compiler... `javac`.

Comment: Being a bit less subtle, Ben clearly meant built rather than compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Maven is a dependency management tool (vastly simplified view, but accurate for our purposes :)

If you have any other way of managing your dependencies (e.g., dropping a wad of jars in a directory and including them on your classpath) that aspect of Maven isn't required to build a binary.

Think of it this way: anything built using Maven may be built *without* Maven by including the depencies manually. Or using another build tool. Or... etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Maven was not managed by Maven from its starting point, but probably after few weeks/months of development, when it was mature enough to do just basic stuff like calling compiler etc. Another example of such case is Git, which had its source code in Git after AFAIR 4 days of development by Linus Torvalds. You know, egg or chicken came first... ;)